# Two outer joins in django's queryset (for language fall back case)

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have two models, Version and Description.

```
class Version(models.Model):
    version_name   = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    version_value  = models.IntegerField()
    url            = models.CharField(max_length=240)

class Description(models.Model):
    version       = models.ForeignKey(Version)
    lang          = models.CharField(max_length=8)
    content       = models.TextField()
```

And a DescriptionSerializer.

```
class DescriptionSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    version_name = serializers.RelatedField(source='version')

    class Meta:
        model = Description
        fields = ('version_name', 'content')
```

They stored the descriptions of different versions in different languages.

E.g.

```
    Version
    +----+--------------+---------------+---------------------+
    | id | version_name | version_value | url                 |
    +----+--------------+---------------+---------------------+
    |  1 | 1.0.0        |             1 | http://abc.net.tw/  |
    |  2 | 1.0.1        |             2 | http://abc.net.tw/2 |
    |  3 | 1.0.2        |             3 | http://abc.net.tw/3 |
    |  4 | 1.0.3        |             4 | http://abc.net.tw/4 |
    |  7 | 1.1.0        |             5 | http://abc.net.tw/5 |
    |  8 | 1.1.1        |             6 | http://abc.net.tw/6 |
    +----+--------------+---------------+---------------------+

    Description
    +------------+-------+---------+
    | version_id | lang  | content |
    +------------+-------+---------+
    |          1 | en_US | English |
    |          1 | zh_TW | Chinese |
    |          1 | es_ES | Spanish |
    |          2 | en_US | English |
    |          2 | zh_TW | Chinese |
    |          2 | es_ES | Spanish |
    |          3 | en_US | English |
    |          3 | zh_TW | Chinese |
    |          3 | es_ES | Spanish |
    |          4 | en_US | English |
    |          7 | en_US | English |
    |          8 | en_US | English |
    |          4 | es_ES | Spanish |
    |          7 | es_ES | Spanish |
    +------------+-------+---------+
```

I'm using django rest framework to implement a web API that returns the description of each version in certain language. If a description of certain language doesn't exist, use English version instead.

I can use following SQL to retrieve the desired result. I've read DRF's docs on relatedField and reverse relation. But I still can't figure out how to use django's ORM to do the same thing and to use it with django rest framework's serializer.

```
select 
    coalesce(d.id, d2.id), coalesce(d.version_id, d2.version_id), coalesce(d.lang, d2.lang), coalesce(d.content, d2.content)
from
    version v 
    left outer join description d on v.id = d.version_id and d.lang='zh_TW'
    left outer join description d2 on v.id = d2.version_id and d2.lang='en_US'
```

Please advise how to do it in django.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use django orm for everything. There are numerous things you can't do with django. For those cases you either use straight up SQL (from django.db import connection, transaction etc...) or if the query results can be worked into objects you have described - then you can use raw queries ([link](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/sql/#performing-raw-sql-queries))